# Python memory use for DataFrames in python script and in Anaconda Spyder

Tags: python, memory-management, anaconda, spyder

Python 101 question. A pandas dataframe is created as:
df1=pandas.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns) # takes up say 100 MB memory
now
df2=df1 # will memory usage be doubled?

What is the effect in a script called something.py and executed as python something.py? Memory is unloaded after completion of execution. Please confirm.

What is the effect when I run something.py in say Anaconda Spyder. The spyder memory will not be unloaded unless I disconnect from the kernel. Is that a true statement?

Thank you all for being patient with a Python newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the effect in a script called something.py and executed as python something.py? Memory is unloaded after completion of execution. Please confirm.

Yes, I think memory is freed after execution.

> What is the effect when I run something.py in say Anaconda Spyder. The spyder memory will not be unloaded unless I disconnect from the kernel. Is that a true statement?

Spyder doesn't hold memory, only the IPython kernel associated with a console does. To free that memory, you need to restart the kernel.

Comment: Gracias Carlos... What about this part: **.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns) # takes up say 100 MB memory now df2=df1 # will memory usage be doubled?**

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. I did a simple test and `df2` is a new copy of `df1`, so changes to `df2` don't affect `df1`.

Comment: Thank you Carlos...can you share how figured this out. I am using windows 10, Anaconda and Python3. Windows memory usage is still a mystery for me. Gracias again!

Comment: I created a simple dataframe in Spyder, assigned to another variablee, dited using Spyder's Variable Explorer, check the other and noticed it hadn't changed.

Comment: Oh...and that is how you determined the second must be occupying different memory space (not referencing the first) hence memory use is twice. Good thinking !

Comment: Yep, that was my thinking.